# Cannot boot (Question Mark folder)

Tags: startup

While my MacBook was connected via HDMI to a external screen it froze and I had to hard-reboot.
Now I have the question-mark-folder-issue-of-the-death.

I reset PRAM and SMC but nothing changed.

When I boot with the alt I have only access to the internet recovery, I can not get the disk util... And I cannot connect to my wifi.

Last, I have a Crucial SSD (2 years old)

Is there a way to know exactly what is going on ? I tried to boot in verbose mode (CMD + V) but it did not work neither.

Answer (score 1):

One would say it is your Disk, it got damaged.

Surprisingly the Verbose does not work at all?

> the "s" key for single-user mode. (Command-S) the "v" key for verbose
>   mode. (Command-V)

If you try the Single user, it should open the terminal.

Alternatively you can use the Internet Recovery mode that already shows as option. Read this from Apple about Internet Recovery mode

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314

If you have a bootable OS X - USB you could use it to try to fix problems as well.

Comment: I can't boot in single user mode neither verbose.

Comment: Than I am sorry to say, but your disk suffered damage. If the Internet recovery is not working you are out of luck.

Comment: Ok, once I have the tools I will try to disconnect and reconnect it but I doubt it will change something... Do you know any tools that could help me save information stored into the SSD or do you think it's a brick know?

Comment: One I do, but you need a second Mac (from a friend or yours) and then use the Target Disk mode. Do you have a bootable OS X USB disk where you could try to start from

Comment: Yep, I have another Mac I could borrow, but I would need a FireWire cable, isn't it ? Or USB would work ?

Comment: FireWire or Thunderbolt cable would work.